# Como obter os amigos e seguidores de uma pessoa no Twitter usando a biblioteca tweepy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, twitter-api

A função `getting_friends_follwers()` abaixo funciona se eu remover o valor 100 de `(cursor2.items(100))` . O meu objetivo é pegar estes nomes (seguidores e amigos) e guardar em um arquivo "amigos.txt".

O problema: O nome `screen_name` possui uma quantidade gigantesca de amigos e seguidores e, assim, a conexão é encerrada pelo Twitter. Pensei em tentar capturar os nomes de 100 em 100 (daí o valor 100 na chamada de cursor2) mas ocorre o seguinte erro:

```
builtins.TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'User' and 'User'
```

Como corrigir?

```
f = open("amigos.txt","w")
Meu = []
def getting_friends_follwers():
    # Get list of followers and following for group of users tweepy
    cursor = tweepy.Cursor(api.friends, screen_name="Carlos")
    cursor2 = tweepy.Cursor(api.followers, screen_name="Carlos")
##    for user in cursor.items():
##        print('friend: ' + user.screen_name)

    for user in sorted(cursor2.items(100)):###funciona se eu tirar este valor!!!
         f.write(str(user.screen_name)+ "\n")


         print('follower: ' + user.screen_name)

f.close()
getting_friends_follwers()
```

Comment: Eu não conheço tão bem o tweepy, mas esse erro deve ser por causa do `sorted`, pois ele não consegue comparar os users retornados pelo cursor para ordená-los

Answer (score 0):

Tente isso

```
f = open("amigos.txt","w")
user = '@Carlos'
count=300 # quantidade de seguidores que será retornado pela api (altere para quantidade que quiser, só cuidado com o limite da api)
   
try:
    followers = tweepy.Cursor(api.followers,screen_name=user).items(count)
                 
    for follower in followers:
         f.write(str(follower.screen_name)+ "\n")
        
except BaseException as e:
          print('failed on_status,',str(e))
          sleep(3)
f.close()
```

Esse deve código faz o que você está procurando, porem o usuário @carlos tem o perfil privado, e não é possível coletar seus seguidores.